# Burned the voltage regulator of a DC motor driver,

Tags: dc-motor, mosfet-driver, brushed-dc-motor

While I check the specs and thought the driver could handle it, after about an hour of discontinuous use, the driver stopped working...

I used the following :
[Motor](https://robodo.in/products/24v-250w-my1016z2-electric-motor-for-e-bike-electric-tricycle-electric-motor)
Specs:
24V 250w,
rated current 13.4 Amps,
No load current <2.2 Amps,
Gear reduction 9.78:1

[With this driver](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://robu.in/product/dual-channel-enhanced-13amp-dc-motor-driver-30a-peak/&ved=2ahUKEwi2vbjZ0ILvAhUbOisKHYCPDm0QjjgwAHoECAEQAg&usg=AOvVaw2MBfc6K-_HcuISppvHrei5)
Dual channel,
5-25 volts
10 amp max continuous in each channel
30 amp max (upto 10 seconds)

While I ran the setup at no load, I checked the temperature of voltage regulator ic 7812 (on the driver board) after 45 mins or so, it was piping hot and the board had stopped conducting.

Also, the operation involved a pwm input from a potentiometer, which would gradually change the speed of motor from 0-300 rpm and had an emergency stop which would immediately turn the pwm to 0.

The motor would start slightly humming even at 0 pwm and would stop with a jerk when used emergency stop.

Please help...

Comment: Where does the 7812 fit in the circuit?  Can you draw a schematic?

Comment: @HandyHowie difficult to get you circuit since cytron drivers are proprietary, but I know it's location on the board if that helps.., it is in the exact middle of the board.

Comment: Did you put your regulator on a heatsink?

Comment: @jwh20 the driver was store bought and I didn't put any heatsink on it

Comment: @user263983 I request you to check out the links of the drivers, the motor was run at no load which consumes 2.2 amps and the spec of drivers allow a voltage of upto 25 volts input

Comment: @user263983 It's a voltage regulator, I did not make the driver

Comment: @user263983 the voltage regulator is on the driver board, please check the link I have put it in the description

Comment: Link is to seller page, not datasheet. Not enough informative. If you sure, you connected properly, board is does not compatible with advertised features

Comment: You should always put a heatsink on a linear regulator that's going to have to handle significant current. I would use a switching regulator for this, honestly, but I just don't like linear regulators.

Comment: I wouldn't buy a module from a company whose name sounds like "rob you"...

Comment: @BrianDrummond my colleges robotics team has been buying products from robu, they're reliable and it may sound like rob u lol, but it's more of an indian pronounciation thing. I attached that link to mainly share the specs, that I may have missed mentioning.

Comment: @Hearth for the motors that I mentioned above, would driving them using mechanical relays work, not looking for precise movement, just to run the motor at slow, medium and full speed...crude implementation